# Can Angular module names include slashes and dots?

Tags: angularjs

We're working on a project structure where each file defines its own module and the module name is literally the path of the file.

For example:

```
//in app.js
angular.module('js/app.js', []);

//in directives/tasks/list.js
angular.module('directives/tasks/list.js', []);
```

Is it possible? What are your thoughts on this naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, slashes and dots are allowed in module names. See Plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ntDGRDKvyfvdWam7FD8w

```
<html ng-app="plunker/test.js">
```

From a naming convention standpoint, I'd find this a bit confusing to anyone new to AngularJS, as they could easily think that is defining the location of the module, not the module name (that "happens" to be in that file). If that's not an issue on your team, then maybe it's fine...

Consider using something separate, but still understandable, like:

```
angular.module('js-app.js', []);
```

Just so it doesn't look exactly like a file reference, but it's understandable to people on the team to be indicative of where the module resides...

Comment: not sure the that plunkr demonstrates the point because the module name doesn't have slash or dots. I changed it a little bit but still fails: http://plnkr.co/edit/RJWl7loy2vqAjRAlN2hS

Comment: btw -- the issue you were seeing in your Plnkr was because of a typo. Take out the semicolon at the end of the first line in your app.js file and your Plnkr will work.